# Wrong audience for JWT using ADAL.js

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

I'm using the `adal-angular` library (but not with Angular) in my SPA to try to acquire an access token that I can use to call the SharePoint APIs (`https://<my-tenant>.sharepoint.com/_api/`).

I've registered an application in Azure AD and enabled the implicit flow in the manifest, and I'm now running my SPA locally, which is why there's a localhost redirect URI. The code below is being executed on startup:

```
const context = new AuthenticationContext({
    clientId: '<my-client-id>',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/signin',
    popUp: true,
    loginResource: 'https://<my-tenant>.sharepoint.com',
    callback: () => window.location.reload()
});

const user = context.getCachedUser();
if (!user) {
    context.login();
} else {
    context.acquireToken('https://<my-tenant>.sharepoint.com', (error, token) => {
        console.log(error, token);
    });
}
```

I'm already logged into the SharePoint site, so with this config everything happens automatically and I see a JWT access token logged to the console. However, when I inspect the token, I see that the audience is `<my-client-id>`. When making a call to `https://<my-tenant>.sharepoint.com/_api/v1.0/me` using the access token, I then get a 401 response with the following error message:

```
{"error_description": "Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown."}
```

I'm pretty sure this all boils down to me not understanding the OAuth2 flow properly, but... how can I acquire a token that SharePoint can actually be used with SharePoint? Am I thinking about this the wrong way? It kinda defeats the purpose if the token retrieved by my app can only be used to authenticate against my own app.

Comment: What kinds of calls will you be making to the SharePoint API? Have you considered using the [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/Quick-Start) instead (which does access your Sharepoint resources) and has much much more documentation and sample code that shows how you can call it.

Comment: Hm, no, I didn't consider that. It will probably do what I need it to. But what about the token audience, won't I have the same issue with that?

Comment: Can you try adding a `/` to the end of your resource url?

Comment: I tried adding the forward slash at the end now, both to the loginResource and the requested resource, but it made no difference - still getting the same audience validation error.

Comment: Is there an additional error message attached with your error_description? Based on that alone, it is hard to say what the issue is. Usually the token endpoint will give a better error message than that.

Answer (score 0):

Getting an access token to SharePoint is well described here:

[OneDrive for Business authentication and sign in](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/aad_oauth.htm)

You should consider first getting a token to the Discovery Endpoint:

> Using an access token received for resource
>   `https://api.office.com/discovery/` you can make a request to the
>   discovery API to learn which services are available

> If the call is successful, the response body contains JSON data with
>   information about the services available for the user and your app.

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https:\/\/api.office.com\/discovery\/v1.0\/me\/$metadata#allServices",
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.DiscoveryServices.ServiceInfo",
      "capability": "MyFiles",
      "serviceApiVersion": "v2.0",
      "serviceEndpointUri": "https:\/\/contoso-my.sharepoint.com\/_api\/v2.0",
      "serviceResourceId": "https:\/\/contoso-my.sharepoint.com\/"
    }
  ]
}
```

There you should get your valid Resource ID... but the issue here may just be that you did not include a forwardslash (`/`) at the end of the Resource URL in your sample code.